# What is the length of magnetic band in a DLT tape?

Tags: backup, tape, dlt

We are currently destroying our old DLT tape (some are 30 years old...), and we are amazed by the length of the band inside.

We would know what is it length ? It looks infinite ! (+1)

Comment: You just took out the tape, you have it all layed out perfectly to measure and you come on here to ask how long it is o.O?

Comment: We don't have tools to measure it in our desks

Comment: All you need is a human body to get a rough estimate.  http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/bodyruler/

Comment: @Zoredache [Our DLT tapes are 900 penises long.](http://www.quantum.com/ServiceandSupport/SoftwareandDocumentationDownloads/DLTV4/Index.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each generation of DLT was different:

- DLT III is [about 365m](http://uk.insight.com/en-gb/productinfo/lto-ultrium-media-tapes/0001492633)
- DLT IV is [about 557m](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/storage/lineup/dlt4/)
- SDLT I is [about 558m](http://www.tape4backup.com/sdlt1-320.php)
- SDLT II is [about 630m](http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Maxell-Super-DLTtape-II-Tape-Cartridge/2628283/product.html)

Answer (score 2):

Standard 40/80GB DLT cartridges have [~557 meters of linear tape](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/storage/lineup/dlt4/) housed inside.

Comment: Is this the same length for all DLT versions ?

Comment: No... this is for the most common 40/80GB DLT IV type.